# Relocating a Blazor Progressive Web Application after installation

Tags: blazor, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

Once a Blazor Progressive Web Application (or any other PWA) has been published then installed on a user device, if I were to re-publish the PWA each client would update to the newer version the next time they open the app, however what if I were to relocate the server? Would this result in orphaned apps? How would I get the already installed apps to find the new server?

I imagine an HTTP 301 would do the trick, but what if this was out of the question? Is it possible to modify the "parent" server via client-side code?

Comment: There would be security issues too. I think you will just have to ask your users to re-install.

Comment: Agree with @HenkHolterman.  A "possible" alternative is to use: [Uniquely identifying PWAs with the web app manifest id property](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/pwa-manifest-id/), but I've not tried it.